# Javascript extension validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, file-extension

So, what i'm tring to do is validate a file extension using javascript/jquery before send to other validation on the server side (php).

I know that has a lot of sources around here, but, i'm trying to make in my own way.

i reach a simple ideia, like the code above:

```
// remove all elements to take only the file name
var fileName        = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop().toLowerCase();  
    validExtension  = ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif','.jpeg']; // list of valid extensions

$.each(validExtension, function (e, val) { // run thru all valid extensions
    if (fileName.indexOf(val) !== -1) { // if found a valid one, stop validation.
        invalidExt = false;
        return false;
    } else { // else, error true...
        invalidExt = true;
    }
});

if (invalidExt) {
    alert('error');
}else{
    alert('success');
}
```

the problem is, if the file have a `.jpg` or any other valid extension in the middle of the name like `desert.jpg.exe`, the validation will pass thru. So, how can i solve this?

Maybe find a way to get the last extension on the file name?

And ofcourse, any tips, be my guest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
var validExtensions = {
    jpg: true,
    jpeg: true,
    png: true,
    gif: true
};


var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().toLowerCase();

if (!validExtensions[filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1)]) {
    alert('Invalid extension');
}
```

- Putting the valid extensions in an object gives you fast (O(1)) lookup times.
- Use `lastIndexOf` to get the last period in the file name.  This way, you're always looking at the extension, regardless of what comes before it.

Comment: nice one, why did you set as +1?

Comment: `'a.b'.lastIndexOf('.') == 1`; `'a.b'.substr(1) == '.b'`.  Adding 1 gets rid of the period.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery :

```
var filename = "photo.exe.jpg";

var validExtensions = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'];
var filenameLowerCase = filename.toLowerCase();
var isValid = false;

for(var i=0; i<validExtensions.length; i++)
    if(filenameLowerCase.indexOf(validExtensions[i], filenameLowerCase.length - validExtensions[i].length) !== -1)
        isValid = true;
```